# create slideshow video using ffmpeg and batch file (Windows) and have all images resized to 1080 height and crossfaded

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, video, batch

I'm trying to create a 1920x1080 slideshow from images in a folder using a batch file and ffmpeg. The batch file references a txt file containing the list of files to be concatenated. The images have varying dimensions and need to be up- or downscaled. All images get concatenated and properly resized when using:

`-r .2 -f concat -safe 0 -i concat_image_list_JPG.txt -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1920:1080 -r 25 -f mp4 "Slideshow 1080.mkv" -y`

but I'd like to add crossfades between them. For some reason, only the first two images are concatenated when using this command:

`-r .2 -f concat -safe 0 -i concat_image_list_JPG.txt -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf zoompan=d=(4+2)/2:s=1920x1080:fps=1/2,framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100 -r 25 -f mp4 "Slideshow 1080.mkv" -y`

What's wrong with the crossfade command? How can I get crossfades and resizing into a single command?

Answer (score 0):

Add `-reinit_filter 0` flag.

According to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524320/ffmpeg-dropping-frames-due-to-color-space-mismatch):

> The issue is that the pixel format within each input changes mid-way. This causes the filtergraph to reinitialize and buffered frames get dropped.
> Suppress reinitialization and convert to a command pixel format before blending.

It is not necessarily the pixel format change (image size maybe?)

```
ffmpeg -reinit_filter 0 -r .2 -f concat -safe 0 -i concat_image_list_JPG.txt -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf zoompan=d=(4+2)/2:s=1920x1080:fps=1/2,framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100 -r 25 "Slideshow 1080.mkv" -y
```

Comment: This now works well for the crossfading: -`reinit_filter 0 -r .2 -f concat -safe 0 -i concat_image_list_JPG.txt -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf zoompan=d=(4+2)/2:s=1920x1080:fps=1/2,framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100 -r 25 -f mp4 "Slideshow 1080.mkv" -y` but in the meantime I figured out how to more elegantly scale images of diffrent aspect ratios and came up with this video filter command: `-vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1:color=black"`. How can I merge this command into the other video filter command?

Comment: Try: `ffmpeg -reinit_filter 0 -r .2 -f concat -safe 0 -i concat_image_list_JPG.txt -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1,scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1:color=black,framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100" -r 25 "Slideshow 1080.mkv" -y`

Comment: Why are you using `-f mp4` for MKV file?

Comment: It got copied from someone elses solution for some other issue I had. Should I remove it? I put all my commands together by trial and error and copying other people's commands. Your new solution does create a slideshow, however, I can't figure out how to parametrize the crossfades which are initiated too fast. I'd prefer them like with the former solution but set to `zoompan=d=(6+2)/2`. Also, images do not keep their aspect ratio as expected with your new solution. The solution in my first comment works well for crossfades and the second vf command for scaling and AR. Can they be combined?

Comment: Regarding `-f mp4`, remove it, since the output is MP4 container with `.mkv` extension. Regarding the aspect ration, you may try removing `setsar=1:1`. I can't see your issue since I don't have your input images. Regarding parametrizing the crossfades, I don't know the answer (I never used crossfades, I just used the filters from your question). You may post a new question regarding crossfades specifically.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing `setsar=1:1` doesn't help. Please save this as a bat file `cd /d "%~dp1"
CHCP 1252
(for %%1 in (*.jpg) do @echo file '%%1') > "%~d1\%~p1\concat_image_list_JPG.txt"
exit`, put a few jpg files of different dimensions into the same folder with that batch file and drop one of the images onto it. The list of images in the folder will be saved as `concat_image_list_JPG.txt`. Then, you can try the commands we have discussed earlier.

Comment: I have tested it with sample frames. It looked OK considered the aspect ratio of the input and output is different. Please post a new question. Add few sample images to the post. Explain the desired output.

Comment: I think the thread title says it all. I want a slideshow of images incl. resizing to 1080, preserving correct aspect ratio plus crossfade between images. My first comment includes your working solution for the crossfading part as well as my separate command for proper resizing. Now we only need to combine the two `-vf` commands properly.

Comment: Crossfade in the title is too general. My answer addresses the specific issue you have descibred. If you don't like my answer it's fine...

Comment: If you want me to delete my answer, please let me know.

Comment: Your answer solves part of what I wanna accomplish. Don't delete it, it might be helpful for others, too. Thanks for your effort, much appreciated!